# Github Environments for private repositories

Tags: github-pages, github-actions

I use GitHub actions to deploy my code. Their [documentation states](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environments) that they have Environments (in beta) that can be enabled. I do not see Environments as an option in the settings of my repository.

Does anyone know how I can enable this?

**Edited to add: I am using a Private Github Repository

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a paid feature and the exact product you need depends on which subfeatures you need.

> For access to environments, environment secrets, and deployment branches in **private** or **internal** repositories, you must use GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, or GitHub Enterprise. For access to other environment protection rules in **private** or **internal** repositories, you must use GitHub Enterprise. For more information, see "[GitHub’s products](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/githubs-products)."

[Source](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation (and now my own recent personal experience), you can get it by subscribing to GitHub Enterprise. You have to move up from that next tier above Team. Hopefully the extra cost will be worth it for everything else that comes along with.

Comment: Github Enterprises cost is 5X Github Team cost. For us, not having the Environment feature available means moving away from Github Actions as our CICD tool.